Почему не даёт вернуть результат функции Java?
import java.util.Scanner;
public class trsin {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner((System.in));
        System.out.print("Write your full name: ");
        String username = input.nextLine();
        sex(username);

    }
    public static String sex(String name) {
        if ('a' == name.charAt(name.length()-1)){
            String gender = "woman";
        }
        else{
            String gender = "man";
        }
        return gender;
    }
}



Ошибка: cannot find symbol 'gender' перед return из-за использования переменной вне зоны видимости (один из дубликатов).  2. Предупреждение (после исправления ошибки): результат, возвращаемый из функции sex -- нигде не используется, то есть тратится впустую -- такой sex не нужен!  3.  Идея определять гендер по последней букве имени не слишком корректна, в том числе и с точки зрения толерантности :)


Возможный дубликат вопроса: error: cannot find symbol в калькуляторе на java

Потому что область видимости переменной gender у вас ограничена if и else (причём, это две разных переменные в if и else, хотя и с одним названием), а снаружи этой конструкции эту переменную уже не видно. Нужно вынести описание gender на уровень всего метода:
    public static String sex(String name) {
        String gender = "man";
        if ('a' == name.charAt(name.length()-1)){
            gender = "woman";
        }
        return gender;
    }

Так то тут переменная вообще не нужна, можно сразу возвращать литерал.

Спасибо большое. Знаю, что переменная не нужна, просто учусь работать с функциями.
